# Section transitions on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to set a transition between sections on a single page application, they are all on the same page but the other sections are set to display none so when I perform an event the display none is toggled for the section requested, now I don't just want the section to come in like that rather set a timeout that would make the section coming in not come in immediately but after like 5s, how can I achieve this, I already tried settimeout but it doesn't seem to work Outline of problem

1. All sections except one have display none,
2. Event is performed on the page that doesn't have display none to bring in requested section and toggle display none
3. Upon request of page, the page transitions in or has a timeout, so the page doesn't swoop in immediately Code below, HTML

HTML

```
<div class="main-container">
       <div class="page padding main" id="page-main">
         <div class="modal hidden">
           <button class="btn-close-modal">&times;</button>
           <h2 class="modal-header">Login to your account</h2>
           <form class="modal-form">
             <div>
               <label for="">Username:</label>
               <input type="text" />
             </div>
             <div>
               <label for="">Password:</label>
               <input type="text" />
             </div>
             <button class="btn header-button">Login &rarr;</button>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
         <nav class="header-nav">
           <a href="#" class="header-img">
             <svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" class="header-svg">
               <path
                 class="path"
                 d="m 15.625507,46.199537 55.767886,-32.030352 55.623047,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311586 0.14485,-64.311586 55.76788,-32.030352 55.62305,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311579 -55.76788,32.03036 -55.62305,-32.28123 55.62305,32.28123 -0.14485,64.31158 -55.76788,32.03035 L 70.958866,207.10393 71.103708,142.79235 126.87159,110.762 71.103708,142.79235 15.480664,110.51112 Z"
                 style="
                   fill: none;
                   stroke: #000;
                   stroke-width: 13;
                   stroke-linejoin: round;
                   stroke-linecap: round;
                 "
               />
             </svg>
           </a>
           <button
             class="header-button login"
             type="button"
             data-page="page-login"
           >
             LOGIN
           </button>
         </nav>
         <div class="header-hero">
           <div class="circle1"></div>
           <div class="circle2"></div>
           <div class="header-text">
             <h1 class="header-text-description">
               Make Banking Easy with Express
             </h1>
             <p class="header-text-texts">
               Together we can make banking awesome!
             </p>
             <p class="header-text-texts">
               Use our mobile app to your need today
             </p>
             <button class="header-button header-buttons" type="button">
               <a href="">Services</a>
             </button>
           </div>
           <div class="header-image hide-for-desktop">
             <img src="./assets/hand.jpg" alt="" class="header-hand" />
             <button class="header-image-1">Transfer</button>
             <button class="header-image-2">Loan</button>
           </div>

  </div>
       <div class="page u-none" id="page-login">
         <nav>
           <a data-page="page-dashboard">User Settings</a>
           <a data-page="page-main">Logout</a>
         </nav>
         <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
         <form action="" name="login" method="" id="form-id" required>
           <label for="name">Name</label>
           <input type="text" id="name" />
           <label for="pin">Pin</label>
           <input type="text" id="pin" />
           <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div class="page u-none" id="page-signup">
         <nav>
           <a data-page="page-settings">User Settings</a>
           <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
         </nav>
         <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
         <form action="" name="login" method="" id="form-id" required>
           <label for="name">Name</label>
           <input type="text" id="name" />
           <label for="pin">Pin</label>
           <input type="text" id="pin" />
           <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
       </div>

       <div class="page u-none" id="page-dashboard">
         <nav>
           <a data-page="page-main">Back to Main</a>
           <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
         </nav>
         <h1>SETTINGS PAGE</h1>
       </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
nav {
      display: flex;
    }
    nav a {
      color: #00f;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* Utility classes */
    .u-none {
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
      animation: 2s fadeIn forwards;
    }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
const ELS_pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');

console.log(ELS_pages);
console.log(ELS_buttons);
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach((EL, i) => {
    // console.log(EL.id);
    console.log(`${i} : ${EL.id}`);
    console.log(id);
    // EL.classList.toggle("u-none", EL.id !== id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (EL.id === id) {
        EL.classList.remove('u-none');
      } else {
        EL.classList.add('u-none');
      }
    }, 20);
  });
};
// goToPage("page-main");
ELS_buttons.forEach((EL) =>
  EL.addEventListener('click', () => {
    goToPage(EL.dataset.page);
  })
);
```

Comment: Use an actual CSS transition. Both `opacity` and position (i.e. `left` & `top`) are supported.

Comment: @ChrisG for what i am doing, if I set opacity, it will take up space on the page, and I don't want that, I don't want the other pages to take up any space except when called upon, just to find a way to ease the way the pages come in that's what I am trying to do instead of the pages just swooping in, do you get what I mean now?

Comment: To fade in a page you have to display it first, even at opacity 0. If you don't want other content to shift, sets its position to fixed or absolute.

Comment: But cant is use settimeout to control the time at which the page comes in, I have spent a lot of time of this project and with my current structure going back to set those things will take a chunk of my time, I am a newbie and I'm trying to get my portfolio up very soon

Comment: What use is setTimeout for a section transition? With a timeout of 20 milliseconds? If you want a delay of 5 seconds, you need `5000`

Comment: i already found a way, thanks a lot, you made me think man, really appreciate you for pushing me, I just had to set a timer on the add and remove class, you get what I mean now right?

Comment: If the only problem was that you used the wrong number for the milliseconds, there's no need to post an answer. This won't be of any use to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting a timer on the add and remove classist style and it worked with what I was opting for. Code below

```
const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach((EL, i) => {
    // console.log(EL.id);
    console.log(`${i} : ${EL.id}`);
    console.log(id);
    // EL.classList.toggle("u-none", EL.id !== id);
    if (EL.id === id) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        EL.classList.remove('u-none');
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        EL.classList.add('u-none');
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
};
```